# How can DBSCAN be applied to image with sobel filter in python?

Tags: python, image-segmentation, dbscan

I already know that To use DBSCAN on images, we need to convert the image into a set of data points.
Considering this, I'm wondering if it's feasible to apply DBSCAN to an image that has undergone Sobel filtering. Specifically, I'm thinking about converting the additional lines or edges that emerge from the Sobel-filtered image. Could this be achieved?
or is there other methods to accomplish this?

I need to use Python to calculate the coil pitch within the catheter

Comment: Are you trying to cluster similar images? please explain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.